# Azure Servicebus not completing all messages within the batch

Tags: python, azureservicebus

So for a little context i'm having problems with the service bus again.

We have a synchronous function app that pulls batches of 500 messages from the service bus, extends the messages with some internal servicebus metadata, concatonates the messages, persists the file and goes back to iterate over the 500 messages to complete them. Snippet of the code:

'''

```
messages = []

with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=SBconnstr) as servicebus_client:
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(topic_name=topic_name, subscription_name=subscription_name)

    with receiver:
        received_msgs = receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=500)
        for msg in received_msgs:
            msg_json = json.loads(str(msg))
            msg_json['enqueued_timestamp'] = msg.enqueued_time_utc.isoformat() 
            msg_json['message_id'] = msg.message_id
            messages.append(msg_json)

        if messages:
            
            timestamp = datetime.utcnow()

            blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(STGconnstr) 
            blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=[redacted], blob=[redacted])

            blob_client.upload_blob(gzip.compress(json.dumps(messages).encode('utf-8')))
                    
            for msg in received_msgs:
                receiver.complete_message(msg)
```

'''

Issue is that out of the 500 messages, only around 50-150 are completed successfully looking from the servicebus metrics side, and without any errors or warnings, EVER.

Also to mention that this behaviour only began on the 22nd of Jan around 8.18pm UTC, suggesting it may be an Azure bug...

Metrics:

[image: metrics]

The strange thing is that I am able to run exactly the same code from databricks, and the completion rate jumps back to 90-100%. The code is identical.

I've had a look at the diagnostic logs for service bus, but there's nothing useful that i could find.

Checked the versions of the servicebus library, but they are undefined during pip install so should be the newest available on both the function app and databricks.

Also tried to use a servicebus library from early in 2023, cant remember the version, but the issues was the same.

Last thing is that we've tried it with the deprecated legacy protocol too uamqp_transport=True, but that didn't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to troubleshoot this with Azure support?

Comment: If your call to `complete_message` does not surface an error, then the service accepted the completion and did not send the client a rejection.   Assuming that is the case, Sean's suggestion is the correct one.  You'll need service investigation, which requires an Azure support case.

Comment: Please post the code as a text, ant an screenshot.

Comment: Reposted the code as text instead of a screenshot, and yeah reached out to azure support, will see what they say.